# App42 - deactivate whole database for update

Tags: app42

Is it possible, to deactive an app (all requests will get a error answer from the app42 service) for a while (or even better, for all except one special user), update the database and after everything is valid again, reactivate the app again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily deactivate your app through dashboard. 
Follow just simple steps:

- Login to your AppHQ Management Console
- Click on View Apps under App Manager section
- Click on Disable to deactivate your app

Same you can follow when you have to activate click on enable.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: this seems to be the only possibility... not what I wanted, but the only solution.. thanks though